# Sum of angles between three intersecting spheres

Tags: euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, spheres, angle

I've been writing a survey on Thurston's construction of a hyperbolic structure on the complement of the figure-eight knot. At one point it is important that the sum of the angles between three hyperbolic planes (find angles between each two, add them up) is $\pi$. I want to show this using Euclidean geometry and the Poincaré disk model in 3-space.

If the spheres $S_1$ and $S_2$ have centers $O_1$ and $O_2$, respectively and $X$ is a point on the intersection, then I can define the angle $\phi_{1,2}$ between $S_1$ and $S_2$ as the unique angle between $O_1X$ and $XO_2$. Is it true that if three spheres $S_1,S_2,S_3$ pairwise intersect, then $\phi_{1,2}+\phi_{2,3}+\phi_{1,3}=\pi$?

Comment: Could you please refer to some sources regarding Thurston's construction?

Comment: $\pi \to 3 \pi/2$ ... Think to mutually orthogonal spheres.

Comment: @zoli At the bottom of [this](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/) page, Chapter 3, is what I'm reading.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't exactly get your hint. Can you elaborate?

Comment: (unless I have not well understood) I mean that if 3 spheres are mutually orthogonal at their intersection point, you will have $\pi/2+\pi/2+\pi/2$, not $\pi$.

Comment: I think the angles will add up to less than $/pi$ just as in 2d hyperbolic geometry